# Playing fullscreen .mp4 video in MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

So I'm trying to play a movie in my tab-navigation bar app. Although its portrait mode, I'd like to play the movie in full screen landscape after pressing a button. Is there some way to present the movie in a modal view controller? Or is it unnecessary?

Could someone please post some code or point me into the right direction? I already tried some code but I just couldn't get it working. I'm sure the video is the right format.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use the MPMoviePlayerViewController in my case...